# mix ecto.create fails (** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification) Ident authentication failed for user "postgres)

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, psql

```
11:06:04.676 [error] GenServer #PID<0.290.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification) Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
    (db_connection 2.4.1) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib 3.17) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol

11:06:04.695 [error] GenServer #PID<0.297.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 28000 (invalid_authorization_specification) Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
    (db_connection 2.4.1) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:100: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection 1.1.0) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib 3.17) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for Helloworld.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

I already tried everything. I am on Fedora 35, i did all that the official Fedora PostgreSQL docs said. I changed the `pg_hba.conf` for this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I setted a password for the user postgres, i initialize it, and nothing happens.

I browsed through some 10 questions here on StackOverflow and none of the solutions works.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace `ident` with `md5` in `pg_hba.conf` and reload PostgreSQL, then you can use password authentication for `localhost` connections.

Comment: Did that and nothing changed. Same error.

Comment: Make sure you have specified the host as `127.0.0.1` and not as `localhost` in your [tag:ecto] configs.

Comment: @HenriqueMonteiro  You won't get Ident failures unless you using ident.  So either you didn't really reload, or the reload failed, or you edited the wrong file, or you edited it wrongly.  If no one else is using the system, it is safer to restart rather than reload.